# How to get closest subset(group of rows) of another group of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, tree

I have data stored in a table in the form of branches of a tree. All these branches were made after a specific iteration process.
However, the sequence of branches made by me and the sequence of actual required branches is not coming exactly same. For clarity, this is the required sequence for the branches.

[image]

And the branches I made are as:

[image]

So, the Branch no. 5 in top image is being assigned Branch no. 4 in my sql query because of all the Red coloured branches made after making all the black coloured branches.

Hence, is there any way, I could shift Branch no. 9 of my sql output to required Branch no. 4 as from the first screenshot, Red Branch no. 4 is the closest subset of Black Branch no. 3. And similarly Red Branch no. 6 is the closest subset of Black Branch no. 5 and then 7 is for 6.

The contents of my sql table is as:

```
    DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(
        State_ID INT,
        BranchNo INT,
        Share FLOAT
    )

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 30500095,    1   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  1   ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500097,  1   ,0.5625
UNION ALL SELECT 30500098,  1   ,0.222222222222222
UNION ALL SELECT 30500099,  1   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500100,  1   ,0.5
UNION ALL SELECT 30500101,  1   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  2   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  2   ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500097,  2   ,0.5625
UNION ALL SELECT 30500098,  2   ,0.222222222222222
UNION ALL SELECT 30500099,  2   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500102,  2   ,0.5
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  3   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  3   ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500097,  3   ,0.5625
UNION ALL SELECT 30500103,  3   ,0.666666666666667
UNION ALL SELECT 30500104,  3   ,0.666666666666667
UNION ALL SELECT 30500105,  3   ,0.75
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  4   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  4   ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500097,  4   ,0.5625
UNION ALL SELECT 30500103,  4   ,0.666666666666667
UNION ALL SELECT 30500106,  4   ,0.333333333333333
UNION ALL SELECT 30500107,  4   ,0.5
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  5   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  5   ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500108,  5   ,0.4375
UNION ALL SELECT 30500109,  5   ,0.285714285714286
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  6   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  6   ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500108,  6   ,0.4375
UNION ALL SELECT 30500110,  6   ,0.714285714285714
UNION ALL SELECT 30500111,  6   ,0.4
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  7   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500112,  7   ,0.904191616766467
UNION ALL SELECT 30500113,  7   ,0.417218543046358
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  8   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  8   ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500097,  8   ,0.5625
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  9   ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  9   ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500097,  9   ,0.5625
UNION ALL SELECT 30500103,  9   ,0.666666666666667
UNION ALL SELECT 30500104,  9   ,0.666666666666667
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  10  ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  10  ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500097,  10  ,0.5625
UNION ALL SELECT 30500103,  10  ,0.666666666666667
UNION ALL SELECT 30500106,  10  ,0.333333333333333
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  11  ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500096,  11  ,0.0958083832335329
UNION ALL SELECT 30500108,  11  ,0.4375
UNION ALL SELECT 30500110,  11  ,0.714285714285714
UNION ALL SELECT 30500095,  12  ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 30500112,  12  ,0.904191616766467

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of my task.

This query brings Branch 9 close to Branch:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    b.branchno AS b2
    ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM @tbl a
INNER JOIN @tbl b
    ON a.state_id = b.state_id
WHERE b.branchno <> a.branchno
AND a.branchno = 3
AND b.branchno >= 3
GROUP BY b.branchno
ORDER BY cnt DESC, b2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple pivot which will give this results:

```
select * from @tbl 
pivot (max(share) for BranchNo in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10], [11], [12])) p
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont want structure to be saved in pivot format as shown in the first pic, but I want the structure to be saved in second pic. Its just that I want the Branch numbers to be adjusted so that the closest subsets may get number next to their supersets only.

Comment: Oh now i see the difference what you are looking for